# mathematical difference between two functions used in scaling data and viewing distribution

Tags: distributions, julia

I am trying to understand the difference between `f(x)` and `g(x)` below. I am not a mathematician or statistician, so please bear with me.

Basically, I'm trying to specifically understand:

1. what `g` is doing to the data
2. what motivation, if any, there is to use `g`
3. what relationship there is, if any, between `f`, and `g` (I do not think one can be algebraically derived from the other, but I could be wrong)
4. what argument one could propose, for or against the use of `g` *or* `f` on the dataset

For example, to me, `f(x)`, or equivalent, `minmax(log(x))` seems a more "natural" way of scaling and looking at the values in `vals`; let us assume that `vals` can have extremely large integer values, and has a more or less logarithmic distribution.

However, I was told that `f` simply "shifts" the data by a constant, and that they're essentially the same function.  This latter statement seems intuitively incorrect to me, partially because the constant is directly dependent on the data (e.g., `min` and `max` of `vals` or `logvals`), and also because the data has different distributions for this input (and the input we actually deal with) --- but I do not have a plausible mathematical argument for why, and perhaps I am wrong in my intution.

On a similar note it just looks like to me that it was mistakenly assumed that `log(x + b) = log(x) + log(b)`, and hence it was acceptable to use the function `g(x)` as a result.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
using Plots
gr()

vals = [4213,2607,2088,1847,1799,1799,1799,1662,1554,1462,1408,1399,1399,1399,1342,1299,1272,1265,1265,1265,1240,1217,1202,1199,1199,1196,1179,1167,1159,1159,1159,1155,1146,1138,1132,1132,1132,1127,1120,1114,1113,1113,1112,1107,1101,1099,1099,1099,1097,1092,1088,1087,1087,1086,1082,1079,1079,1079,1076,1073,1071,1071,1071,1068,1066,1065,1065,1064,1062,1060,1060,1060,1058,1056,1056,1056,1055,1053,1052,1052,1052,1050,1049,1049,1049,1047,1046,1046,1046,1044,1043,1043,1043,1042,1041,1041,1041,1040,1039,1039,1038,1037,1037,1037,1036,1035,1035,1035,1034,1033,1033,1033,1032,1032,1032,1031,1031,1031,1030,1029,1029,1029,1029,1028,1028,1028,1027,1027,1026,1026,1026,1026,1025,1025,1025,1024,1024,1024,1024,1024,1023,1023,1023,1023,1022,1022,1022,1021,1021,1021,1021,1021,1021,1020,1020,1020,1020,1020,1019,1019,1019,1019,1019,1019,1018,1018,1018,1018,1018,1018,1017,1017,1017,1017,1017,1017,1016,1016,1016,1016,1016,1016,1016,1015,1015,1015,1015,1015,1015,1015,1014,1014,1014,1014,1014,1014,1014,1013,1013,1013,1013,1013,1013,1013,1013,1013,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1011,1011,1011,1011,1011,1011,1011,1011,1011,1011,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1009,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1008,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1007,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1004,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000]

(min, max) = extrema(vals)

logvals = map(log, vals)
(logmin, logmax) = extrema(logvals)

f(n, min, max) = (log(n) - log(min)) / (log(max) - log(min))
g(n, min, max) = (log(n - min + 1)) / log(max - min + 1)
minmaxscale(n, min, max) = (n - min) / (max - min)

fDistribution         = map((n -> f(n, min, max)), vals)
gDistribution         = map((n -> g(n, min, max)), vals)
minmaxlogDistribution = map((n -> minmaxscale(n, logmin, logmax)), logvals)

println("Input values: ", vals)
println("f(x): ", fDistribution)
println("g(x): ", gDistribution)
println("minmax(log(x)): ", minmaxlogDistribution)

assert(minmaxlogDistribution == fDistribution)
assert(fDistribution != gDistribution)

p = histogram(fDistribution,  yaxis=(:log), bins=100, linecolor=:black, linewidth=1, fillrange=0, fillcolor=:lightpink, fillalpha=0.25, lab="f(x) Histogram")
histogram!(gDistribution, yaxis=(:log), bins=100, linecolor=:black, linewidth=1, fillrange=0, fillcolor=:lightblue, fillalpha=0.25, lab="g(x) Histogram")
```

[image]